# Labeling posts for later recall

Tags: support, bookmarks

Is it possible to tag posts, so they can be followed later? Specifically, there are some posts that pose interesting questions; they don't have an answer yet, and I'd like to read their answers in the future.

Is that possible now?

Comment: Star them. That's what the favorite feature is for.

Comment: or just use your browser's bookmarking feature, if you want an option for the entire internet, rather than just SE sites.

Comment: @Servy - tell me more

Comment: @Servy: You can bookmark the entire Internet?  I didn't know that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's what I'm here for.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have said: You can star them using the button underneath the voting panel, or, because question URIs are stable, just use your browser's native bookmark functionality.