# Need an answer later button

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There should be an option to add a question to answer it later. I come across a few questions while doing a Google search, but every time we cannot answer them due to time issues. Currently, I am using the bookmark button to save it.

But the problem is we don't go back to the bookmark section to answer them. With the answer later, we can notify the user they saved a few questions to answer them later in the notification section.

I think this will be useful. Your thoughts?

Comment: The Bookmark and Follow feature really are all you need, in my opinion. If you go back to them to answer them or not is up to you.

Comment: Does the bookmark give any notif? And with follow I guess I get notif for many actions on the question. But answer later will give notif only once, and it will be easy to find which answer I marked to answer later.

Comment: No, the bookmark doesn't give notifications; but like I mentioned that's all you really need.

Comment: Create a bookmark folder in your browser for the question you want to answer later. Why should Stack Overflow dedicate resources to developing something that has a very easy workaround?

Comment: You have a point @Dharman I am not forcing stack overflow developers to do it. Just asking if this can be implemented. If we can use the browser bookmark why add a bookmark button in stack overflow?

Comment: To be able to track new activity.

Comment: Activity with no notification? At least I am not getting notified, I need to manually move to bookmark to check and it is hard to understand why it is highlighted as unread

Comment: Perhaps You want something like a browser extension like the "snooze" feature in Firefox; this closes/hides the tab for a period of time and then reopens it later, when the timer completes. You can then answer the question when the tab reopens. There are plenty of solutions for this "problem" outside of adding a new feature to SO itself.

Comment: I will try to elaborate on why this feature is needed inside the StackOverflow website. @Larnu

Comment: You'll need a *very* **strong** and compelling reason for why it needs to be within SO then, @RajendranNadar, when the "problem" can easily be solved with the tools within the site and/or with basic browser functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Labeling posts for later recall](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255588/labeling-posts-for-later-recall)

Comment: Yes, this a good idea. It could be generalised to a feature for ***tagging bookmarks*** (by user-defined tags, private or public) and being notified on one or more of the tags, including time-based notification, say exponentially increasing/decreasing time intervals, with *"Remind me later"*, *"Remind me sooner"*, and *"Never remind me"* options (in addition to filtering/searching capabilities, e.g. ***only display bookmarks with a particular tag***). All like tagging/searching for questions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm always for providing categorisation for bookmarks. Yet, sadly neither SO seems interested in it, nor even other uses. I often see responses like "just search by tags in the bookmarks" yet that doesn't allow me to differentiate which question I've bookmarked because I want to *read* later or which because I want to *write an answer to* later. And many I've bookmarked for easy access as they are dupe targets. There is no current way to do this with the bookmark system on-site. And the browser bookmarks are also limited in how they can handle this.

Comment: How should the site know when you have time to answer? Normally we look at the notification as they come up, at least for checking what it is about (we don't know what it is until checking it.) So, if it were an answer later one, it is also gone after checking... at the end nothing gained (or almost nothing) || or we stop checking notifications, risking to miss some *important* one

Comment: @user16320675 it is not the responsibility of the site we will label which is for future reading & which one to answer in future. Notification will be a general one like "Hey, there are X posts that you tagged to answer later" we can notify maybe monthly once.

Comment: I have not wrote it is the responsibility of the site to label anything!! The problem I see is: the site does not know when you have time, so it will notify you at some time that eventually is not appropriate, you have to check the notification (at least to know which type it is), and the notification will be gone. What was the *gain*? despite having more (ignored) notifications

Comment: "But the problem is we don't go back to the bookmark section to answer them." - there is the problem, solve it. This is a people problem rant trying to masquerade as a technology problem. If you're not going through your own bookmarks then it wasn't that important afterall.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus what if I have 2K bookmarks out of which 1.5K are my favoured solutions (So I can't remove from bookmark) & 20 I thought of answering later, now I don't know which I marked to answer later? Any solution for this?

Comment: @RajendranNadar then it's time to delete some bookmarks. (or use your browser's favorites tooling, most of which offer named folder functionality)

Comment: Yes, browsers have allowed folders for decades. So make a folder for favoured solutions and an "answer later" folder

Comment: @MonkeyZeus and how exactly do you use that across four devices, three operating systems, 3-5 browsers, and at least two sync profiles? Why should people invest *even more time* into jury rigging some system that may work or not instead of extending the existing system on SE?

Comment: @VLAZ well because at some point people are going to want Stack Overflow to do their taxes for them as well... the next step for this feature is to become a full blown todo feature.

Comment: @Gimby Slippery slope fallacy.

Comment: @VLAZ I think most people would agree that the current system, internally and externally, is not ideal. Yet, what does the suggestion here really offer to improve this? I mean not vaguely in that some notify-later would magically make people answer. When to notify? Delay, date, inaction, ...? How to notify? Notifications, emails, dashboard, ...? How many people would actually use that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the suggestion was to use browser bookmarks. Something that very often gets touted as a solution. I directly tackled that - the browser bookmarks. Do *you* think that what I described above doable directly with browser bookmarks?

Comment: @VLAZ that's pretty much the point - it IS a slippery slope. Boundaries are important, Stack Overflow should not become overloaded with half-finished features because they are somewhat useful even though you can manage it with better existing tooling.

Comment: @Gimby how can I manage what I described *better* with existing tools?

Comment: @VLAZ "Do you think that what I described above doable directly with browser bookmarks?" I don't. But also I think most people don't have that case – for them it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi using PC + phone is enough to have issues with bookmarks.

Comment: @VLAZ Using PC + phone is enough to have issues with *more than just SO* bookmarks. Why stop at that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because we're on SO, discussing SO features. In particular, the bookmarks feature. We can stop, if you agree that no feature of SO ever can be made better. Until then I'd like to think that there is room for improvement.

Comment: @VLAZ Is https://www.raymond.cc/blog/sync-your-bookmarks-across-browsers-systems/ not good enough? I still don't understand the need for it to be SO specific.

Comment: If we can use other tools why other features are added like upvotes, comments, etc. We can add questions here copy the link and paste it on Reddit to get answers & upvotes there, instead of implementing it here on SO in the past, nice idea right? @MonkeyZeus. Most users derailed the topic without understanding the need for this feature.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus let's flip that argument then - why *do* we need bookmarks on SE? Surely we can all just sync our bookmarks externally - shouldn't we abolish this feature? We further have RSS feed readers, why bother with the "follow" feature? Because *it's more convenient*. I myself have no idea why this pushback on *extending* the features that already exist. You're trying to claim it's unneeded *but the feature is already unneeded*. I don't see you petitioning to remove it, though. So, which is it - can we use convenience features or not?

Comment: @RajendranNadar Those can be classified as community-building tools which encourage engagement and I think they've done quite well. This bookmark suggestion is merely a failure of personal management. If you want to participate in the Reddit community then no one is stopping you. Do note that posting a link-only question here would be received quite poorly as opposed to doing the same on Reddit because this community has standards. Tell me, what happens when you decide to move to [Codidact](https://codidact.org/)? You expect them to also implement this bookmark feature?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Don't worry I will create a proper question with some use cases in future! You can wait for that. I am asking for a feature in SO because I use this website everday. I used Reddit as an example.

Comment: @VLAZ When the heck did they rename it to bookmarks? Wasn't it called "favorites/starred" or something like that? Quite frankly, it should be removed or have the ability to categorize your favorites into folders I guess. I don't see a benefit to "hey SO, remind me to look at these specific posts at a future date" for the masses.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "*When the heck did they rename it to bookmarks?*" [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558) "*or have the ability to categorize your favorites into folders I guess.*" that *is* what I'm saying here. I agree the "remind me later" is highly specific but I wouldn't just reject it. If implemented, I'd find use for such a feature to review old question. Right now such reviews are ad-hoc and inconsistent, so it could be better. But I'd first love to see other improvements.

Comment: @VLAZ If you're suggesting a specific review tool enhancement then that certainly seems viable since it is for the greater good rather than the niche needs of one. In my 8+ years of participation I have apparently favorited 3 questions; none of which are obvious as to why I marked them as such. I cannot imagine that having thousands of questions favorited is anything short of information overload. Choosing to favorite thousands of questions instead of answering a few sounds like a cry for help more than anything. This is really **not** a technology problem as I stated before.

Answer (score 17):

I don't see the point.

One can already bookmark, follow, or otherwise track questions both inside and outside of Stack Overflow. If one does not feel motivated enough to even look at one's tracked questions, I doubt one would be motivated enough to answer them.

Comment: We can bookmark a question for many reasons (Like we liked the approach, waiting for a good answer, etc), but we mark it as an answer later to answer it later in future.

Comment: And you can remove the bookmark for many reasons, too; such as when you answered the question that you bookmarked so you can answer it later, @RajendranNadar .

Comment: @RajendranNadar You can for example already use *browser* bookmarks to collect "answer later" questions to a separate category. There are so many ways to do this already, and so many ways a tailored solution would be complex, I don't see a point why [se] should invest the effort.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if I agree with you, the bookmark button in the stack is also useless I can bookmark the question in my browser. Why bookmark in stack website?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's useless, @RajendranNadar . Some of us prefer to not have 10's of bookmarks in their browser, so being able to "bookmark" within the application is a nice to have. :)

Comment: @RajendranNadar The major difference between the bookmark button and your answer-later button is that the bookmark button *already exists*. It takes practically zero effort to have it in the future.

Comment: I just opened my bookmark section & found 5 posts as unread, now I am unsure why it is highlighted as unread?

Comment: This is suggesting that the status quo of the current UI is fine and that being able to filter follows or bookmarks within the UI should not be considered. I disagree with the premise that the status quo is fine. Compared to many modern web apps the SE approach is still poor with regard to user interactivity

Comment: @charlietfl This answer is suggesting that the proposal is not convincing. Whatever people think this suggests about "the status quo" is purely make believe. "X is fine" and "X is not improved by Y" are two separate things.

Answer (score -2):

There is auto-saved draft. If there were reminders about drafts saved and a page to review them, this would be a neat solution, as it doesn't involve adding more buttons to track questions (we have two, bookmark and follow, ought to be enough).

Comment: The reminder should be sent only once after a month I add it to answer later?

Comment: [SE only stores 1 draft for the answer and it will be automatically deleted after 1 week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/241919) though. This won't help for multiple questions.